# Converting a C# app using long poll to use Websockets on windows 7

Tags: c#, windows-7, websocket

I have an existing desktop application that uses long polling to receive notifications to use websockets. My development is on Windows 7 I have a websocket server running out on our network. When I would like to replace the notifications to use websockets, and this only needs to be a listen only.

I everything I find says websockets are only available on Windows 8.

- Is there no way to create a listen only websocket connection to an existing web socket server?
- If windows 8 is only development, can it be build on windows 8 then deployed to a Windows 7?
- Is there a work around that does not involve third party installation?

Comment: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid not. `System.Net.WebSockets` is not supported on Windows 7. So if you try to run an application that uses that namespace, no matter if it is server or client, it will throw a `PlatformNotSupportedException`.

You will need to install a third party client to be able of connecting to a WebSocket server.

Take a look at

https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp

https://github.com/Olivine-Labs/Alchemy-Websockets-Client-Library

http://websocket4net.codeplex.com/